# Draw animated GIF in ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, animated-gif

I want to draw animated GIF in a cell of `ListView` in my WinForms application.
This is a part of code where I try to do that:

first of all I load image from the resorce:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Form
{
    Image bmp = Properties.Resources.loader;
    bool animated = false;
    ....
```

and then I load GIF in `DrawSubItem` event on `ListView`:

```
private void listView1_DrawSubItem(object sender, DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
    {
        if (!animated)
        {
            ImageAnimator.Animate(bmp, new EventHandler((object _o, EventArgs _e) =>
            {
                this.Invalidate();
            }));
            animated = true;
        }

        ImageAnimator.UpdateFrames();
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, e.Bounds.Location);
    }
    else
    {
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.SubItem.Text, this.Font, e.Bounds, SystemColors.ControlText);
    }
}
```

it displays the image but not animated.
I would be very grateful if someone has an example of painting animated GIF in `ListView` cell.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/4f3465b0-7126-4f86-b2e3-e5ecc336b1c8/how-to-show-animated-gif-images-in-datagridview?forum=winformsdatacontrols). The accepted answer let you download a demo

Comment: This is not possible. You can only add a Picturebox and overlay it it on the cell. Hacky, imo and will only work while the PBox has focus. Or you could pull the frames out and draw them in a Timer. Urgh!

Comment: Sure it's possible. The workaround is to replace `this.Invalidate();` with `listView1.Invalidate()`